# MySQL import using zcat log time script is complete

Tags: mysql, zcat

We need to run a test import before doing things in our live environment but need to know how long the import takes.

The file 10Gb at Max compression, when uncompressed its around 170 Gb. In the past when we have run tests it has taken around 9 hours which is too long to sit in front of a PC and watch :-)

Is there a way to log how long the import takes / when it finished.

We are running this command to import the script:
`zcat /import_file.sql.gz | mysql -u 'root' -p database`

If we were able to log a time to a file once the script is completed that would be perfect.

I am aware of "show table status;" but we are unsure what the last table is called so this kind of doesn't help.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why don't you log the time with the shell script used for running the command in the question?

Comment: @Shadow I'm not sure what you mean. How would I do that? I just want to know the time when it finishes or know how long it took to finish.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer you can use the time command and then log the output to a file.

here is the command: `{ time zcat /import_file.sql.gz | mysql -u 'root' -p database ; } 2> time.txt`

the `2>` with store the output into the `time.txt` file. I hope this helps anyone with this issue.